# How to mirror traffic on one interface to another?

Tags: networking, 18.04, iptables, traffic

I'm basically trying to implement a tap-interface on wlan0 interface (Ubuntu 18.04), i.e., mirror every packet going through wlan0 (incoming and outgoing) to another interface (tap0).

I've got tap0 up using the following configuration in **`/etc/network/interfaces`**:

```
allow-hotplug tap0
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
    pre-up ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root
    pre-up ip addr add 192.168.2.52/24 dev tap0
    up ip link set dev tap0 up
    post-up ip route del 192.168.2.0/24 dev tap0
    post-up ip route add 192.168.2.52/32 dev tap0
    post-down ip link del dev tap0
```

I've then tried routing traffic from wlan0 to tap0 with these iptable rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tap0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I then tried listen to the traffic on tap0 with **`tcpdump -ni tap0 -vv`** but it shows no packets.

P.S.:
I've also tried the following approaches:

**Approach-1:**
Bringing up tap interface by editing **`/etc/rc.local`** with:

```
tunctl -t tap0
ifconfig tap0 192.168.2.52 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.52/24 -j MASQUERADE
tcpdump -ni tap0 -vv still shows no packets.
```

**Approach-2:**

```
# For incoming traffic
tc qdisc add dev wlan0 ingress
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent ffff: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev tap0

# For outgoing traffic
tc qdisc replace dev wlan0 parent root handle 10: prio
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 10: \
   protocol all prio 2 u32 \
   match u32 0 0 flowid 10:1 \
   action mirred egress mirror dev tap0
```

Please help.
Thanks!